# Ignoring spaces and merge two branch with git

Tags: git, diff, git-merge

How can I merge the next example with git:

```
[master]
       \-->[branchA]->[code1]->[commit]->[branchA]->[code2]->[commit]->[branchA]
                                            \-->[branchB]->[code3]->[commit]->[branchB]
```

next:

```
[branchA]->[merge]->[code2]->[branchB]->[code2 + code3]->[code5]->[branchB]->[expected merged code ignoring white spaces]
```

I execute the next git commands:

```
git branch branchA
git checkout branchA
  ... modificate code.....
git commit -m 'code1'

git branch branchB
git checkout branchB
  ... modificate code.....
git commit -m 'code3'

git checkout branchA
  ... modificate code.....
git commit -m 'code2'



git checkout branchA
git merge --strategy=recursive --strategy-option=ignore-space-change branchB
```

here I expect [code5]

but...the resulting merge don't merge, end in a conflict merge.

**What Git merge do:**

[image: What Git merge do]

**What P4Merge do and I wish git merge will do:**

[image: What P4Merge do]

**Git log:**

[image: LOG]

I upoaded de code to github, actually is not merged.

**Github code:
https://github.com/ballgas/gitwhitespaces**

Comment: Are you trying to accept one branch's version over the other?

Comment: The missing piece of information is what that block of code looked like at the point when B branched off from A: the common ancestor between A and B. That's the third part of a three-way merge, A, B, and their last commit in common.

Comment: I have added a better explanation.  Can help me?

Comment: Are you trying to get `11111111` and `22222222` to align automatically? I'm  not sure I understand why you merged A into B and then B back into A.

Comment: Is B branched off master or A?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish. I *think* what you want is for Git to match alignments for you in the merge? It won't do that. Ignoring whitespace is only for the purposes of determining what lines have changed. Those which have changed (ie. `11111111` and `22222222`) will have their whitespace faithfully retained. Git doesn't understand what it's merging, it's just text. It can't realign indentation for you.

Instead use an automated code indenter to solve those sorts of problems (and many related ones).

But there's a problem with how you're describing the merge. Particularly this.

```
git branch branchB
git checkout branchB
git merge --strategy=recursive --strategy-option=ignore-space-change branchA
```

The first line creates `branchB`, presumably off `branchA`. If so, `branchA` and `branchB` will point to the same commit (all creating a branch in Git does is add a new label to the current commit). Merging them will do nothing because they are the same commit.

I'm also not sure why you're trying to merge B back into A just after A has been merged into B.

I don't know if that's what you actually ran, or a transcription mistake. Running `git log --graph --decorate` might help you to visualize what's going on.

Comment: What i want is that if one line is identical from branchA and branchB (ignoring white spaces) don't merge the line of branchB into branchA. This will result in code correctly aligned, because branchA have the correct aligment that I want to have.

Comment: How can I preserve the lines of branchA and only get the modifications of branchB. But ignore the the lines that are identical but have diferent white spaces.

Comment: @Sergio You've already got it, `git merge --strategy=recursive --strategy-option=ignore-space-change`. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: I also think it is the correct command, but checking the code still shows me hundreds of lines marked as changes by the white spaces. I attached a picture of one example. 
I found a way to do what i whant but editing the code before the commit using P4Merge,

Comment: @Sergio Yes, that's expected with `--strategy-option=ignore-space-change`. It tells Git to consider lines with only whitespace change as unchanged, so they won't be merged. Isn't that what you wanted? Really if this is just about alignment, run an automatic code formatter and be done with it.

Comment: I added better example. O created a git example.

Comment: @Sergio I'm sorry, I still don't understand what you're expecting. Git will not change the indentation of a line. Since A and B are written with different indentations, you're always going to get them misaligned in an automatic merge. Where did `33333333` come from?

Comment: "33333333" is code that only have branchA.  I add a new image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133578/discussion-between-schwern-and-sergio).

Comment: OK, Thanks. But can you wait me. I will by busy now :/
I uploaded the code to github:
https://github.com/ballgas/gitwhitespaces